# Transactional Replication Questions

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have the following questions about how transactional replication handles the following. For the sake of example, assume database 'A' is being replicated (via transactional replication) to database 'B'.

1. If a table in database ‘A’ is dropped, will the table get dropped in ‘B’?
2. If a table in ‘A’ is renamed, what happens to the table in ‘B’?
3. If we drop a column in a table in database ‘A’, what will happen to the column in the same table in database ‘B’?
4. If we rename a column in a table in database ‘A’, what will happen to the column in the same table in database ‘B’?
5. Is replicating stored procs, views and UDF’s are optional?
6. Is there any way to avoid all the stored process being created in database ‘B’ as a result of it being the subscriber of a replication?
        a. If not, can we at least dictate what schema they are created in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of your questions are answered here: [Frequently asked questions for Replication Administrators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151740.aspx)

1. You cannot drop a table that is replicated. You have to first drop the article.
2. You cannot rename a table that is replicated. You have to first drop the article.
3. Issuing ALTER TABLE … DROP COLUMN at the Publisher, will result in the command being replicated to the Subscriber.
4. You cannot rename a column "whilst" it is being replicated. You need to remove it from replication first.
5. Yes, it's optional.
6. What do you mean by created?

All of these items can be tested very easily by creating a very simple Replication topology on a test server. I suggest you do so in order to both plan for and practice your changes.

Comment: I guess I should have stated that replication would be disabled first. And then, once restarted, how are the six situations mentioned in my post handled?

Comment: @Randy Minder: I assume by disabled that you plan to stop the Log Reader and Distribution Agents. Even so, the answers remain the same. Read through the Microsoft documentation for Replication, you will find the answers to all your questions and more there, it's very thorough.

Comment: @JohnSansom Thanks for your answer john. How do I specify copy views to the subscriber?